# How to change ActionButton's width in splitActionBar (Bottom)

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

How to change ActionButton's width in splitActionBar
in ActionBar or SherlockActionBar
like this photo

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vnrpi.png

thanks

Comment: I'm betting you can change this by overriding the style for this. I'd peruse the source for whatever theme you are using for the style to override.

Answer (score 1):

The ActionBar will manage button width and how many buttons appear on it itself.

There is nothing you can do to influence this,

You can add a custom view to the ActionBar in which you can put any views you like but I believe this will only show on the top bar.

Comment: Yes, I use custom View in BottomBar, 
but width is longer than my view.
I try to set ActionButton minWidth, but not working. [Bad in English]

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a way to solve my problem.
My previous way was set each menu button a MenuItem, but I can't control it's width.
My new solution is put all of menu in one MenuItem, 
and set LayoutParams(screenWidth, wrap_content), problem solved.

Thanks to everyone.